# Google AnalyticsService throwing java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

In my code this line

```
   DataFeed dataFeed = analyticsService.getFeed(query.getUrl(),DataFeed.class);
```

throwing java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException,

I tried with both this query URLs

```
1. DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL("https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data"));
2. DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data"));
```

sometimes for some id's it is giving result but most of the time it is throwing the exception any suggestion please, it is killing my time

These are my query parameters

```
 query.setStartDate(startDate);
 query.setEndDate(endDate);
 query.setIds(tableID);
 query.setDimensions("ga:pagePath");
 query.setMetrics("ga:pageviews");
 query.setSort("-ga:pageviews");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself by including one more query parameter

```
 query.setStringCustomParameter("key","my-key");
```